NetSuite REST API Bulk/Batch Operations
I'm writing a C# library/project that will integrate the NetSuite ERP with our software. Basically the premise is that I want to be able to import and export data from NetSuite in and out of our system in bulk, since we could potentially be dealing with thousands of records. When I query the customer endpoint, for example, it provides a list of links to each individual customer. Is there a way to hydrate those records? The hydration can work via SuiteQL, with a crude solution being something like select * from customer, however I feel like I'm missing a first-class solution here.
This also is a problem in the export direction (ie. POST to NetSuite). Is REST Web Services just unsuitable for this usage? Is a RESTlet more or less my only option here? It feels like there is a first-class solution that I am overlooking in the documentation.
Thanks in advance!
